# How to navigate to VF page from a lightning component with javascript?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, lightning-experience

I have a button in a lightning component onclick of which I want to navigate to a visualforce page (which will open in lightning experience only). Is this possible with javascript? If yes, then how can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**By using navigatingToURL**

In Component

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
        <ui:button label="navigateToURL" press="{!c.gotoURL}" />
</aura:component>
```

In controller

```
gotoURL : function(component, event, helper) {
    var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    urlEvent.setParams({
        "url":"vfpage url"
    });
    urlEvent.fire(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using navigatingToURL.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToURL.htm

Or you can first go to apex controller from javascript controller and then navigate to VF page. For navigating to apes controller, refer to below link

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm

Answer (score 0):

Hi in case if you don't want to hardcode the url use this to get the current page base UrL as it is best way to do it. Helpfull if using community

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var urlString = window.location.href;
     var baseURL = urlString.substring(0, urlString.indexOf("/s"));
     component.set("v.cbaseURL", baseURL);
},
performprint : function(component, event, helper){
   // var currentURL = '{!$Site.BaseUrl}';
    //console.log(currentURL + ' ' + window.location);
    var currentURL =window.location.href;
    if(currentURL.indexOf('/s')){
        var n = currentURL.indexOf('/s');
        currentURL = currentURL.substring(0, n != -1 ? n : currentURL.length);
    }
    currentURL = currentURL + '/apex/TermsAndConditionPrint';
    console.log('currUrl>>',currentURL);    
    window.open(currentURL,'_blank');
    // window.parent.location.href="{!URLFOR($Site.Prefix+'/apex/TermsAndConditionPrint?rec=')}"
      },
```